Watermark not progressing on Beam pipeline reading from Kafka
I'm having trouble with a Beam (v2.58.1) pipeline I've written in Kotlin and deployed to GCP Dataflow that reads from a KafkaIO source. No matter what I try, the pipeline always exhibits the same behaviour. The "data lag" shown in the job graph rises by however long the job has been running, the data watermark and system watermark don't update, the data freshness metric goes up linearly, and the backlog climbs and causes autoscaling to ramp up to the maximum number of instances. I've read a lot about watermarks and windowing and triggers and tried a lot of different configurations as well as emitting custom timestamps using WithTimestamps or outputWithTimestamp but nothing is working. It's not a very complicated pipeline and none of the steps is taking a long time to complete so I'm a bit lost.
For what it's worth, I'm not really interested in event time and if I can just use processing time somehow that would be ideal. I just want to take 30-second groups of data from Kafka, group them by some shared attribute as well as the start of the minute of a timestamp within the record, and emit a merged version of those groups.
Here is a summary of what the pipeline is doing:
pipeline
            .apply(
                "Read from Kafka",
                KafkaIO.read<ByteArray, ByteArray>()
                    .withBootstrapServers(options.kafkaBootstrapServers)
                    .withTopic(Topics.x)
                    .withKeyDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer::class.java)
                    .withValueDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer::class.java)
                    .withConsumerConfigUpdates(
                        mapOf(
                            "client.id" to "x",
                            "group.id" to "x",
                            "max.partition.fetch.bytes" to 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                            "fetch.max.bytes" to 200 * 1024 * 1024,
                            "fetch.min.bytes" to 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                            "max.poll.records" to 2000,
                        )
                    )
                    .withProcessingTime()
            )
            .apply(
                "Apply window",
                Window.into<KafkaRecord<ByteArray, ByteArray>>(
                    FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.windowDuration))
                )
                    .triggering(
                        Repeatedly.forever(
                            AfterFirst.of(
                                AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(options.groupBatchSize),
                                AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow(),
                                AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                          .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(options.windowDuration))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(options.windowDuration))
                    .discardingFiredPanes()
            )
            .apply("Convert byte arrays to protobuf objects", ParDo.of(ConvertByteArraysToProto())) // simple protobuf conversion
            .apply("Transform input", ParDo.of(TransformInput()))
            .apply("Group and merge stats", Combine.perKey(MergeStats()))
            .apply("Log result", ParDo.of(LogValue())) // basic log out

...

    internal class TransformInput :
        DoFn<KV<KafkaKey, KafkaValue>, KV<KafkaKey, TransformedData>>() {
        @ProcessElement
        fun processElement(
            @Element record: KV<KafkaKey, KafkaValue>,
            out: OutputReceiver<KV<KafkaKey, TransformedData>>
        ) {
            val key = record.key
            val value = record.value

            // truncate timestamp so results can be grouped by minute
            val truncatedTimestamp = value.report.endTime.asInstant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
            val keyBuilder = key.toBuilder().setTimestamp(truncatedTimestamp.asProto)

            val transformedValue = TransformedData.fromKafka(value)

            out.output(KV.of(keyBuilder.build(), transformedValue))
        }
    }

    class MergeStats : SerializableFunction<Iterable<TransformedData>, TransformedData> {
        override fun apply(input: Iterable<TransformedData>): TransformedData {
            val now = Instant.now()
            val builder = TransformedDataBuilder.initFrom(input.first())

            for (item in input) {
                builder.merge(item)
            }

            return builder.build()
        }
    }



I eventually want to emit the final result back to Kafka but I've been trying to make it work with a simple log output first. The logged output all looks correct but I don't know if it's missing values or not.
Some things I've tried

Using a FixedWindow instead with a trigger firing every 30 seconds or when the max records is reached
Adding .apply("Assign Timestamps", WithTimestamps.of { _ -> Instant.now() }) after the DoFn's
Emitting using out.outputWithTimestamp(etc, Instant.now()) in the different DoFn's
Different Kafka configs
Lots of different windowing configs
Different merge functions (e.g. one using the accumulator class)
Timing all the DoFn's to make sure none are taking too long
Using Combine.perKey(MergeStats()).withHotKeyFanout()
Windowing after changing the timestamp to the start of the minute
Reshuffles
Using GroupIntoBatches.ofSize instead of Combine.perKey
Enabling dataflow prime
Using --experiments=pre_optimize=all
Using streaming engine and runner v2

If anyone knows anything I can try, or anything I could do to debug the issue I'd appreciate it. Maybe I should be looking at the window associated with the datapoints but I'm not sure how to do that.

Hi @Bonnici, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Its possible the consuming from Kafka itself is the problem here. I'd suggest checking the following, to try and diagnose the issue.

Are you seeing any messages downstream of the windowing function, if you simply add a DoFn to log them out?

If you remove the windowing function entirely, do you see messages, and does the problem go away?


This will isolate whether the issue is in consuming from Kafka, or in your windowing configuration

Yep I'm seeing messages go through the windowing function and all the way to the output. I've also removed windowing and grouping and seen the data lag stay at a stable number without growing out of control.
